# Activating Multi User on CM12.1 Android 5.1

Tags: cyanogenmod, 5.1-lollipop, multi-user

I've done the edit to the build.prop

```
fw.show_multiuserui=1
fw.max_users=5
```

I've done this on a tablet using CM12.1 (android 5.1) and it hasn't activated Multi User.  Is there anything els that needs doing?

Or maybe there is something that needs doing at build time when the code is compiled?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Did you get closer to solving this issue? Is Multi User not enabled by default? What device do you have? Hope to solve your issue.

Comment: I'm afraid it didn't work. It's a kindle fire HD 7", device Id is Tate

Comment: This seems to be a known issue: http://forum.cyanogenmod.org/topic/114977-no-more-multiusers/  but I can't find more information on the subject...